# Estimating the cluster size - Executor heartbeat timed out

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a spark job doing below operations:

- read 7 day data from a delta table (~500 GB/day * 7 = ~3.5 TB)
- few filter and transforms - using max on window function, collect_set, explode on array fields
- repartition(10) during write, write as json format ,partitioned by year_month and week

  - also tried coalesce(10) during write, same error
  - doing repartition/coalesce for one of the requirement to have specific number of files per run
- Output Size in delta : 6 GB per day * 7 = ~45GB (estimating based on earlier 1 day successful run)

**Cluster Configuration:**

- n2d-standard-16 cluster (GCP VM) on Databricks
- 5 worker , 1 Driver
- Databricks has 200 shuffle partition at cluster level

**Error**:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1193.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 12445) (10.35.1.130 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 150302 ms

Looked at the plan, scan/exchange jobs are successfully completed. However other job with stage (ShuffleQueryStage-window-sort-Window-ObjectHashAggregate-WholeStageCodegen-exchange) is failing.

How do we know why the job is failing or how to estimate the correct cluster configuration so that job runs successfully?

**Transformations**:

```
condition = ((col("year") == 2024) & (col("month") == 2) & (col("day").between(12, 18)) & col("id").isNotNull() & col("id").rlike(id_pattern))
df = spark.read.format("delta").table("<delta_table_name>")
df = df.filter(condition).select(required_cols)

df = df.withColumn('year_month', expr("max(concat(year(timefield), lpad(month(timefield), 2, '0'))) over()")) \
      .withColumn('week', weekofyear("timefield"))

for c in aggregation_cols:
    df = df.withColumn("max_time_"+c, max("timefield").over(Window.partitionBy("id","week",c)))

exprs = [
    collect_set(
        when(col(c).isNotNull(), struct(col(c).alias("name"), unix_timestamp(col("max_time_"+c)).alias("timestamp")))
    ).alias(c+"_agg")
    for c in aggregation_cols
]

aggregated_df = df.groupBy("id","year_month","week").agg(*exprs)
```

[image]

**update** : removed repartition(10)/coalesce(10), still running into same error.